# Delete Data fom Mysql After 24hrs

Tags: php, mysql

hello i am working on a database where i want to delete data which is 24hrs old ...

and i am using now() to insert data ..... 
here is my insert code

```
INSERT INTO counter_ads (page,ip,time) VALUES ( '$page', '$ref', NOW())
```

can any one help i want if time column is old than 24hrs it should get delete ... with mysql query.
 i want something like

```
DELETE FROM counter_ads WHERE NOW()-24 > time
```

i know this will not work but something like this

thx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```sql
DELETE FROM counter_ads WHERE time < NOW() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR
```

You could also consider automating such a process using MySQL's [event scheduler](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/events.html), if so desired.

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM counter_ads WHERE `time` < NOW() - interval 1 day
```